# Hyperlink of a website on email body doesn't open the website?

Tags: hyperlink, server, gmail, html-email, mailgun

I have sent an email with a hyperlink of my website from my website to my gmail acoount.

When I clicked to the link from the email body it redirects me to the https://sso.secureserver.net/?app=email&realm=pass rather than opening my website.

I have used mailgun services to send the email.

Hyperlink on email body looks like

http://email.domain.com/c/eJxVjcsOgyAQRb9GlmQGsI4LFtjE_xgFlQYfKSakf1-6bHJX5yTneksP5cMsolWABIgddqABJUo3mF45GMiNLbZP3RgInD-JVz6inM9dbFbRYkgjssHgWyDsJ_QTwEJLmIzvRLLbfV-50a5RY10pRf5XKhRve4bMLz5UPVl3julnvj6BLj0" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?hl=en&q=http://email.domain.com/c/eJxVjcsOgyAQRb9GlmQGsI4LFtjE_xgFlQYfKSakf1-6bHJX5yTneksP5cMsolWABIgddqABJUo3mF45GMiNLbZP3RgInD-JVz6inM9dbFbRYkgjssHgWyDsJ_QTwEJLmIzvRLLbfV-50a5RY10pRf5XKhRve4bMLz5UPVl3julnvj6BLj0&source=gmail&ust=1516334964874000&usg=AFQjCNEXF_nntbRA67yc_OPpvPJ0vsKGzw

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try sending the whole HTML structure not only <a href="somithing.php"></a>. I'm not sure but it worked for me.

Comment: Please edit your question to improve readability.

Comment: It is not a problem of HTML structure.HTML structure is fine.The only issue is redirection.

Comment: What is the intended url your area trying to send the user to? Use that in the href?